# statesave not working with datatables when rows are added dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatables, yui-datatable, datatables-1.10

I am using DataTables and I initialize the table with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        stateSave: true
    } );
} );
```

I populate my table dynamically using $('#example').row.add(...)

When I reload or revisit my page, the table is empty again.  Is stateSave supposed to work with dynamically inserted row entires?

Comment: what browser are you seeing this in?

Comment: chrome.  but a table with pre-populated entires is working (that is, datatables remembers my sorting)

Comment: State is not data. `State.save()` does not save the content of the table, only such as pagination position, display length, filtering,  sorting. See -> https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave

Answer (score 2):

Try changing stateSave to bStateSave.  Worked for me when my code had this same issue.
So the code would be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        bStateSave: true
    } );
} );
```

Comment: He is using the latest version of datatables which uses `stateSave`

Answer (score 1):

State save isn't used to save data - only pagination etc..

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have localstorage enabled! Encoutnered this myself and it wasn't enabled which caused the issue.